# "Getting Data" error - Powerapps with Sharepoint list as data source

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I know this may sound basic but im having trouble running my poweapps application. It sticks to "Getting Data". Im using sharepoint as data source

Im expecting the application to load the data and show the form that needs to be filled up by the user.

Comment: is this a standalone canvas app or power apps customized list form?

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. Check if the account has permission on SharePoint list by which PowerApp is running.
2. Remove the SharePoint connection and then add it again.
3. Check if the SharePoint list is having more than 5k items, if yes then increase the threadhold of Powerapp